# Form posts no values (only on Mac Safari)

Tags: javascript, forms, macos

We have this form that works on FF, Chrome and IE on PC.

On Mac with firefox it posts no values to the next page.
The page posted to does not receive the form input values...

I can't find out what's wrong...

Any help is highly appreciated as I'm going nuts ;-)
Thanks,
Bas

```
<form name="f2" action="index.php?option=com_content&amp;task=view&amp;id=62&amp;Itemid=76" method="post" onsubmit="return checkMeasures(this)">
```

Javascript:

```
function checkMeasures(form) 
{

    var elem = form.elements;
    var distances_array = new Array();
    var variables_array = new Array();
    var chosen_pool_shape = 0;
    var compare_with_index = 0;

    for(i=0; i<elem.length; i++)
    {
        if (elem[i].name.indexOf("-") != -1)
        {
            distances_array[i] = parseInt(elem[i].value);
            variables_array[i] = elem[i].name;
        }
        else
        {
            if (elem[i].name == "chosen_pool_shape")
            {
                chosen_pool_shape = elem[i].value;
            }
        }
    }

    var half_array = distances_array.length/2;

    for(index=0; index<half_array; index++)
    {
        var count = index;
        compare_with_index = half_array+count;
        if(distances_array[index] == 0)
        {
            alert('De maten van het winterzeil zijn niet compleet.');
            return false;
        }else if(distances_array[compare_with_index] == 0)
        {
            alert('De maten van het zwembad zijn niet compleet.');
            return false;
        }else{
            if ((distances_array[index] < 20) || (distances_array[compare_with_index] < 20))
            {
                alert('Gelieve centimeters in te vullen in plaats van meters! Verander het winterzeil / Zwembadametingen < 100.');
                return false;
            }
            if ((variables_array[index] != "C-E") && (variables_array[index] != "F-D"))
            {
                if (distances_array[index] <= distances_array[compare_with_index])
                {
                    //document.write(distances_array[index] + distances_array[compare_with_index]);
                    alert('Fout: Het winterzeil moet groter zijn dan het zwembad. Gelieve uw afstand(en) aan te passen zodat het zeil over het zwembad hangt.');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with this javascript code, it only seems to check for errors and make the submit if it is true, not posting any values. I think you need to look somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Have you ran it in Safari and seen what the Console said, if anything?

Comment: It would be easier to help you when you give us a link to that page.

Comment: @Andy is on the right track. Try removing the `onsubmit` handler. Are the params passed along? If not, then try replacing your params with something simple like `foo=bar`. Does that work?

Comment: Sorry 
The form is on the page after this one:
http://winterzeil.be/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=60&Itemid=80

On the page above please click the button "Select pool shape"

The page that opens is the page with the form with the problem.
Thanks a lot!

Bas

Answer (score 1):

Crazy enough it was a missing ; that I overlooked...

onsubmit="return checkMeasures(this)"

Did not work...

onsubmit="return checkMeasures(this);"

Does work!

Finally found it :-)